# Как сделать чтобы программа на java не закрывалась автоматически после открытия .bat файла?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Программа генерирует название электронной почты и случайный пароль для нового сотрудника. В среде разработки в консоли программа хорошо отрабатывает, но мне нужно сделать в идеале,чтобы был файл, например `.exe`, при двойном клике мыши он открывается и выполняется эта программа.

Я создал jar файл в среде разработки Intelij IDEA, но он не запускается, поэтому я сделал .bat файл, в котором прописал следующее:

```
start java -jar EmailApp.jar
.bat
```

Файл запускается, НО! Как только я нажимаю клавишу, программа сразу закрывается, а мне нужно,чтобы программа не закрывалась и показала мне данные.

Клавишу я нажимаю, чтобы сделать выбор, к какому департаменту относится сотрудник, и дальше уже идёт следующее выполнение программы.

В идеале должен получится один файл, который выполняет программу(показывает созданный email и пароль на экране)

Главный класс **EmaillApp**:

```
package emailapp;

public class EmailApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Email em1 = new Email("Petya", "Ivanov");

System.out.println(em1.showInfo());
 }
}
```

Класс **Email**:

```
package emailapp;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Email {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String password;
private String email;
private int defaultPasswordLength = 10;
private String department;
private String companySuffix = "supercompany.com";
private int mailboxCapacity = 500;
private String alternateEmail;

//Constructor to receive  the first name and last name
public Email(String firstName, String lastName) {
this.firstName = firstName;
this.lastName = lastName;


//Call a method asking for the department - return the department
this.department = setDepartment();


//Call a method that returns a random password
this.password = randomPassword(defaultPasswordLength);


//Combine elements to generate email
email = firstName.toLowerCase() + "." + lastName.toLowerCase() + "@" + 
department + "." + companySuffix;

}
//Ask for the department
private String setDepartment() {
System.out.print("New worker: " + firstName + " " +  lastName + 
"\nDepartment Codes: \n1 for Sales\n2 for Development\n3 for Accounting\n0 
for none\nEnter department code: ");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int depChoice = in.nextInt();
if (depChoice == 1) {return "sales";}
else if (depChoice == 2) {return "dev";}
else if (depChoice == 3) {return "acct";}
else {return "";}
}

//Generate a random password
private String randomPassword(int length) {
String passwordSet = "ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789!@#$%";
char[] password = new char[length];
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  int rand = (int) (Math.random() * passwordSet.length());
  password[i] = passwordSet.charAt(rand);
 }
 return new String (password);
 }

//Set the mailbox capacity
public void setMailboxCapacity(int capacity) {
this.mailboxCapacity = capacity;
}

//set the alternate email
public void setAlternateEmail(String altEmail) {
this.alternateEmail = altEmail;
}

//Change password
public void changePassword(String password) {
this.password = password;
}

public int getMailboxCapacity() { return mailboxCapacity;}
public String getAlternateEmail() {return alternateEmail;}
public String getPassword() {return password;}

public String showInfo() {
return "DISPLAY NAME: " + firstName + " " + lastName +
        "\nCOMPANY EMAIL: " + email +
        "\nPASSWORD: " + password +
        "\nMAILBOX CAPACITY: " + mailboxCapacity + "mb";

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На основной вопрос уже ответили, я же отвечу на вопрос автора топика из комментариев:

> Подскажите ещё как можно сделать так,чтобы после того как программа отработала, мне выплыло сообщение о том, хочу ли я снова создать email и прочие данные(запустить программу снова) и программа запустилась ещё раз?

Я не настоящий сварщик, тоже совсем недавно начал знакомиться с Java, но в примере показал, как воспользоваться бесконечным циклом для вашей программы, а дальше можно под свои нужды отредактировать. Правда, немного увлекся.

```
    package emailapp;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmailApp {
    // Один объект сканнер на всю программу, который закрываем перед выходом по EXIT
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // В этом методе создаем Email объект
    private static Email createEmail() {
        String firstName = "";
        String lastName = "";

        System.out.println("Enter the name: ");
        firstName = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the last name: ");
        lastName = sc.nextLine();

        return new Email(firstName, lastName);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Список, куда будем добавлять элементы и сразу выводить на экран
        ArrayList<Email> list = new ArrayList<>();
        // Счетчик для списка
        int cycleCount = 0;

        System.out.println("Let's create some emails!\n");

        // Эта конструкция служит бесконечным циклом. Ее можно переписать на (int i = 0; ; i++) и заменить cycleCounter на i, суть та же
        while(true) {

            Email em = createEmail(); // Создаем Email
            list.add(cycleCount, em); // Добавляем в лист
            System.out.println(list.get(cycleCount).showInfo()); // Показываем по нему инфо
            cycleCount++; // Итерируем счетчик

            // Если на этом моменте ввести EXIT, то цикл завершится и программа закроется. Можно вводить любую строчку,
            // кроме EXIT, чтобы цикл начался заново
            System.out.println("Do you want to create a new worker? Enter YES to continue or EXIT to exit");
            if ("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(sc.nextLine())) {
                sc.close();
                System.exit(0);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cycleCounter++; // Итерируем счетчик  загорелся красным цветом, при запуске выдает ошибку, java can't find symbol

Comment: Я исправил cycleCounter++ на cycleCount, программа запустилась, видимо в этом была ошибка. НО! после того, как выбираю номер департамента, у меня появляется запрос на продолжение или выход, а надо чтобы дальше продолжалась программа, то есть создавался email, пароль, и надпись с колличествоом мб почты, а уже потом сделать эту надпись для продолжения или выхода. Как этот код можно поправить?

Comment: @kentforth с cycleCount действительно, это я опечатался. По поводу вывода на экран метода showInfo() : необходимо строчку с ним исправить на System.out.println(list.get(cycleCount).showInfo()). Поправил код в посте.

Comment: @kentforth Просто ваш метод showInfo() сразу возвращает свои данные, а нужно было их просто обернуть в метод вывода на экран.

Comment: Все так, как я хотел, Благодарю за ответ, вы мне очень помогли!

Answer (score 5):

Вам нужно дожидаться ввода пользователя и обрабатывать его.

В Java для этого нужно считать данные из `System.in` используя метод, который блокирует исполнение, наприрмер, с помощью [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
...
System.out.println(em1.showInfo());
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.nextLine();
```

Можно это сделать и непосредственно в *.bat файле, с помощью `pause`:

```
start java -jar EmailApp.jar
pause
```

Comment: Подскажите ещё как можно сделать так,чтобы после того как программа отработала, мне выплыло сообщение о том, хочу ли я снова создать email и прочие данные(запустить программу снова) и программа запустилась ещё раз? то есть создать такой фикл, при котьором программа постоянна бы запускалась

Comment: @kentforth Такую логику я бы в bat-файле писать не стал. Лучше реализовать в Java: выводить e-mail в бесконечном цикле и после каждого вывода спрашивать у пользователя: нужно ли продолжить. Выводить сообщения уже умеете, считывать можно с помощью `Scanner`, читайте документацию.

Comment: я просто не знаю как мне сделать,чтобы сделать отдельный файл, который бы запускался по двойному клику и выполнялась эта программа, jar файл сделал, но он не открывается(по двойному клику ничего не происходит) вот и сделал батник

Comment: @kentforth все понятно. я просто уточнил, что логику взаимодействия с пользователем лучше писать в одном месте и удобнее в Java.

Answer (score 4):

Не нужны вам bat'ники. Просто добавьте в саму программу ожидание реакции от пользователя:

```
public class EmailApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Email em1 = new Email("Petya", "Ivanov");
        System.out.println(em1.showInfo());

        System.out.println("Press ENTER to continue");
        System.console().readLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! помогло!

Comment: @kentforth [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

```
...    
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        scanner.nextLine();
    }
...
```

OR

```
... 
        try {
            System.console().readLine();    
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
...
```